# ArgumentCountError Too few arguments to function Illuminate\View\Factory::startSection(), 0 passed in

Tags: laravel

I try to load admin dashboard on localhost and this the error i get on my ecommerce project.

ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\View\Factory::startSection(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\Ecommerce\storage\framework\views\acd890c98309210d45617b3d87cde84379fbb9c2.php on line 9 and at least 1 expected (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\Ecommerce\resources\views\admin\index.blade.php)

[This my index.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9QsX.png)

[acd890c98309210d45617b3d87cde84379fbb9c2.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEkyD.png)

Any assistant on this will be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Your section should be `@section('content')` and end it with `@endsection` only

Comment: Its has worked out. Thank you

Comment: great! happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget @endsection to end your section

@section('content')

//Your content

@endsection